# How can I pass a matrix from a subprogram into main()?

Tags: c, matrix, transpose

In the below code, there is a subprogram with prototype `float transposed_matrix(int n, int m, float (*a)[m]);` through which I am trying to pass into the main program its result: a transposed matrix. This is so that I can print it from `main()`. Anybody could help me complete the code? Thank you very much! :-)

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define R 2
#define C 3

float transposed_matrix(int n, int m, float (*a)[m]);

int main(void)
{
  int n=2,m=3;
  int i,j;
  float A[n][m],&transposed_matrix[i][j];

  puts("Enter the values of the matrix:");
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    for(j=0;j<m;j++)
    {
      printf("A[%d][%d]=",i,j);
      scanf("%f",&A[i][j]);
    }

  puts("\nThe transposed matrix is:");
  transposed_matrix(n, m, A[R][C], &transposed_matrix[i][j])

  for(i=0;i<R;i++)
  {
    for(j=0;j<C;j++)
      printf("%6.2f",transposed_matrix[i][j]);  
    printf("\n");
  }

  return 0;
}


float transposed_matrix(int n, int m, float A[R][C], float (*b)[m])
{
  int i,j;
  for(i=0;i<C;i++)
  {
    for(j=0;j<R;j++)
       (*b)[m]=A[j][i];  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays decays to pointers to their first element.

If you have a simple array like

```
float simple_array[SIZE];
```

Then it will decay (as `&simple_array[0]`) to the type `float *`.

If each element in the array is in turn an array, then the decay only happens for the first level, and you still get a pointer to the first element of the "outer" array. This will be a pointer to an array.

So for an array like

```
float A[n][m];
```

then it will decay (still using `&A[0]`) to the type `float (*)[m]`.

Remembering that you need to pass the sizes of the array to the functions, the `transposed_matrix` declaration could look like:

```
float transposed_matrix(int n, int m, float (*a)[m]);
```

Comment: thanks a lot @Someprogrammerdude! I just edited my question to incorporate your comments, and give it a go. However, I am still struggling to get it to work. Any chance you can update your answer so that I can complete this? Thank you very much!!

Comment: You are right @Someprogrammerdude, apologies for editing the question! I will give it a go and think about it thoroughly as I can't seem to figure it out yet. If you happen to be able to edit my code to make it run, that would be great. If you paste it in your first answer, I can accept it as the final solution. Thank you again for all your help :-)